# Find the electrode potential of a solution

Tags: electrochemistry

I'm stuck with the next exercise.

What  is the electrode potential (against NHE) in the solution prepared by adding 90 mL of $\ce{ KI }$ 5.0 M to 10 mL of $H2O2$ 0.10 M, with a buffer at pH 2.0?

First I wrote the reduction half-reactions

$$ \ce {I2(s) +2e- ->2I-} $$
$$ \ce {H2O2 +2H+ +2e- ->2H2O} $$

then I wrote the complete reaction where $ \ce {H2O2} $ reduces and $ \ce {I-}$ oxides with the number of initial and final moles

$$ \ce {H2O2 +2H+ +2I- ->2H2O + I2(s)} $$
$ \ce {Initial:   0.001 n H2O2 , 0.045n 2I-  } $

$ \ce {Final:   x  H2O2 , 0.043+x  2I-   } $

and as the products are solid or liquid they have standard concentrations

Since it is not easy to know x, I proceeded to use Nernst's equation to find the potential of the electrode with the pair of iodes and knowing that the $E$ for this is $0.5345 V$

$$\ce {E = 0.5345 - \frac{0.05916}{2} log({\frac{0.043n}{0.1L}}})^2 = 0.5305V$$
but when I see the correct answer it appears as $0.419V$ and I don't know where is my mistake :c thanks for read. <3

Comment: The initial solution contains $ 0.45 mol$ $\ce{KI}$ in $100 mL$, with a concentration $4.5 M$. It contains also $0.001 mol$ $\ce{ H2O2}$, with a concentration $0.01 M$. The final concentration of $\ce{KI}$ is $4.48 M$. This is sufficient to allow you to calculate the electrode potential of the $\ce{ KI}$ solution